# Counting custom post type with wp_count_posts returns an empty object

Tags: custom-post-types, count

For some reason the `wp_counts_posts` function returns an empty object if I use my custom post type's name in the function's parameter. The `var_dump` is:

`object(stdClass)#93 (0) { }`

The name of my cpt is `CommunityUpload` and I use the count function as follows:

```
function community_gallery_post_count(){
$posts = wp_count_posts( 'communityupload' );
var_dump( $posts );
return $posts->publish;
```

The function returns as expected if counting standard posts.

I define my cpt as follows:

```
[...]
var $single = "Community Upload";   // this represents the singular name of the post type
var $plural = "Community Uploads";  // this represents the plural name of the post type
var $type   = "CommunityUpload";    // this is the actual type
function add_post_type(){
$labels = array(
  'name' => _x($this->plural, 'post type general name'),
  'singular_name' => _x($this->single, 'post type singular name'),
  'add_new' => _x('Add ' . $this->single, $this->single),
  'add_new_item' => __('Add New ' . $this->single),
  'edit_item' => __('Edit ' . $this->single),
  'new_item' => __('New ' . $this->single),
  'view_item' => __('View ' . $this->single),
  'search_items' => __('Search ' . $this->plural),
  'not_found' =>  __('No ' . $this->plural . ' Found'),
  'not_found_in_trash' => __('No ' . $this->plural . ' found in Trash'),
  'parent_item_colon' => ''
);
$options = array(
  'labels' => $labels,
  'public' => true,
  'publicly_queryable' => true,
  'show_ui' => true,
  'query_var' => true,
  'rewrite' => array('slug' => $this->slug),
  'capability_type' => 'post',
  'hierarchical' => false,
  'has_archive' => true,
  'menu_position' => null,
  'supports' => array(
    'title',
    'editor',
    'author',
    'thumbnail',
    'excerpt',
    'comments',
    'custom-fields'
  ),
);
register_post_type($this->type, $options);
}
[...]
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Why are you using `var` and are you using this code inside a class?

Comment: When is the function `community_gallery_post_count ` called?

Comment: @PieterGoosen no real reason for var, just a way of storing a variable, why? Yes, it is inside a class that gets instantiated in child theme's functions.php

Comment: @engelen the function is called inside `bp_core_new_nav_item` function, that I call to create custom BuddyPress menu item with `'name' => __( sprintf('My Gallery(%d)', community_gallery_post_count()), 'buddypress' )`

Comment: And on what action do you call `bp_core_new_nav_item`?

Comment: @engelen `bp_setup_nav`

Comment: And when are you calling `add_post_type` (on what action)?

Comment: @engelen `init`

Comment: Could you try using a lower priority to `add_action` for the `add_post_type` callback (e.g. `add_action( 'init', 'add_post_type', 5 );`) and let me know if that works? If it works, I'll add an answer explaining it.

Comment: Go ahead, explain it :) (it works!)